# open CV -how can I write a code for a timer

Tags: c++, opencv

how can I write a code for open cv (c++) where I want to put a 5 second timer, so I want to track an object and after 5 seconds pick up the object.

how can you write a code for the timer part

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use the implementation of Songho: http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html. It is very simple and convenient. Another plus: it works for Windows, Linux, and Unix.

Songho's timer consists of two files, `Timer.h` and `Timer.cpp` which you simply add to your project. Its usage is quite simple (copied from the link above):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Timer.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Timer timer;

    // start timer
    timer.start();

    // do something
    ...

    // stop timer
    timer.stop();

    // print the elapsed time in millisec
    cout << timer.getElapsedTimeInMilliSec() << " ms.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And if you don't like this timer you can still take it a reference for your own.

You didn't add a lot of details about your use case, but a hack-ish solution could consist of starting the timer at the same time you start your tracking and then check the value of the timer at every iteration of your algorithm:

```
bool timerStarted = false;
bool reallyStationary = false;

while( ( ! reallyStationary ) && /* other conditions */ )
{
    // Track the object ...

    if ( /* object is stationary */ )
    {
         if ( timerStarted )
         {
             if ( timer.getElapsedTimeInSec() < 5 )
                 reallyStationary = false; // Continue the while-loop.
             else
                 reallyStationary = true; // Leave the while-loop.
         }
         else
         {
             timer.start()
             timerStarted = true;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( timerStarted )
        {
            timerStarted = false;
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
}

if ( reallyStationary )
{
    // Pick up an object.
}
```

Comment: thank you that should help a lot. sorry I did not explain it properly. it should be that the arm is tracking the ball continuously, however if the ball remains stationary for 5 seconds, the arm will pick it up

Comment: I have tried to update my answer according to the details from your comment.

Comment: I managed to add and that part of the code however i'm still getting errors: if (x >= 640 / 3 && x <= 640 / 1.5 && y >= 160 && y <= 320 && (!reallyStationary))
     {
      if (timerStarted)
      {
       if (timer.getElapsedTimeInSec() < 5)
        reallyStationary = false; 
       else
        reallyStationary = true; 
      }

      else
      {
       timer.start()
        timerStarted = true;
      }


     }
     else
     {
      if (timerStarted)
      {
       timerStarted = false;
       timer.stop();
      }
     }

Comment: im still getting a few errors, from these functions: timer and timerStarted